# Find the Friday after Next in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, truncate

I have a weird situation where I need to make a DueDate to be the following Friday.

So if the date is Monday, March 11th 2019 then the DueDate is Friday March 22nd.

I am able to do this easily with:

```
TRUNC(Next_Day(FilingPeriod, 'FRI')) + 7 as DueDate
```

My issue comes when the day is Friday March 15th 2019 ad it should also have a DueDate of Friday March 22nd, instead it has a DueDate of Friday March 29th.

And I get why. I have been looking for a way to simplify this or throw in a check to determine if the current date is a Friday and go from there.

I have looked for a bit and read similar questions but I still can not seem to find it. 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Just subtract 1 from the date before using `NEXT_DAY()`:

```
TRUNC(Next_Day(FilingPeriod - 1, 'FRI')) + 7 as DueDate
```

Comment: How did I not think of that. It's been a long week! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Get back to Monday, the first day of the ISO week. Then go plus 4, then plus 7 days:

```
TRUNC(FilingPeriod, 'iw') + 11
```

On a sidenote: I'd avoid `NEXT_DAY` whenever possible. The day name depends on the current language setting and `NEXT_DAY` has no parameter to override this. This renders the function rather dangerous, because it makes a query fail-prone.